# how to bind picture with content in itext when picture is large?

Tags: itext

I encounter a problem: for example, I want to insert a picture in page 1 after some content, but my picture is very large so the picture will insert in page 2 and the page 2 content will appear in page 1, so how to bind this picture with page 1 content, and the page 2 content will appear after picture?

Comment: Can you atleast post your code? And maybe a screenshot of your current output.

Comment: @Sucy your code is formatted like gobblygook when you put it in a comment. Edit your question, then delete your comment. Thank you!